# Proving distance preserving map is affine linear

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a map $T: \mathbb{E^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E^n}$ that preserves distance. Prove that it is affine linear.
How does one do this? What's the approach? Looking at colinear points?

Comment: Euclidean norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that for any $n+1$-tuple of points $(e_0,\ldots,e_n)$ in general position in $\Bbb{E}^n$, the map
$$\Bbb{E}^n\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}^{n+1}:\ p\ \longmapsto\ (|p-e_0|,\ldots,|p-e_n|),$$
is injective.